# Making AJAX Requests Using WebView

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, webview, uiwebview

The title says it all... Can I make ajax requests using webview? My UI will be all native-android code but to access the back-end, I need to use ajax. I do know how to make ajax calls using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use a Java HTTP client.

Comment: @SLaks Is it still possible though? And why not? (just curious)

Comment: Because going through JS and a WebView will make it multiple orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: @SLaks Oh, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. make sure that you enabled the javascript for the webview via `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` [read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean))

Comment: So where should I keep the html if I want it localized in the app?